# mtr python and linux

Tags: python, linux

I am doing an MTR implementation on linux using python code from a script located at https://github.com/catalyst/smokeping-mtr-alert/blob/master/smokeping-mtr-alert.

The line of code that is of concern to me is

```
mtr_command = "mtr -n --report %s" % pipes.quote(args.hostname)
```

I wish to modify the output of mtr to give the granular details I want using the `-o` option, specifically I want to add `-o "LSRD NBWA JXIM  V"` but obviously the code cannot be

```
mtr_command = "mtr -n --report %s -o "LSRD NBWA JXIM  V" % pipes.quote(args.hostname)
```

How can I add my output modifiers to get the output I need?

Answer (score 0):

```
 mtr_command = 'mtr -n --report %s -o "LSRD NBWA JXIM V"'% pipes.quote(args.hostname)
```

or

```
mtr_command = 'mtr -n --report {0} -o "LSRD NBWA JXIM V"'.format(pipes.quote(args.hostname))
```

Try using single quote on the outer command string and double quote on the inside

Comment: Your single quotes `‘` are unicode `U+2018`, are you sure it is what you expected ?

Comment: I tried running that command and the output modifiers were not applied